# Conditionally display multiple variables in MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This is a college assignment.

We have these checkboxes in a userform.

Let's say I have three checkboxes which are:
Find Max,
Find Min,
Find Average

These find the max, min and average values from a certain range.
My problem here lies with the MsgBox.
After the program does the calculation based on the choices, there will be a MsgBox that displays these values.

How do I create a MsgBox that displays the choices I have selected previously?

If I could create a MsgBox for each choice, that would be easier, but this assignment requires that they all appear in a single MsgBox.

If I chose only Max and Min, then the MsgBox should display just the Max value and Min value. If I choose only Max, then the MsgBox should display the Max value. If I choose all, then the MsgBox should display all of them.

I'm thinking I could create a MsgBox for all possible scenarios, but I actually have six choices here that should be displayed whether they were selected or not in the userform. I feel this would be not very effective. I guess there must be some conditional coding between the userform checkboxes and the MsgBox.

Comment: You need to concatenate a string that forms the message body. The body will obviously include the resulting checkbox values. Use vbcrlf for new lines to format the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
Sub ShowResults()

    Dim sMessage As String

    ' btnMax btnMin btnAvg - use your controls names
    If btnMax.Value = True Then
        sMessage = sMessage & "Max is: " & CStr(yourMAXvalue) & vbNewLine
    End If

    If btnMin.Value = True Then
        sMessage = sMessage & "Min is: " & CStr(yourMINvalue) & vbNewLine
    End If

    If btnAvg.Value = True Then
        sMessage = sMessage & "Avg is: " & CStr(yourAvgvalue) & vbNewLine
    End If



    If Len(sMessage) > 0 Then MsgBox sMessage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Userform with (Name):fmrCalculator & Caption: Calculator
2. Create 3 labels with Caption: Max, Min & Avarage
3. Create 3 Checkboxes with (Name): cbxMax, cbxMin & cbxAverage
4. Create 1 CommandButton with (Name): cdbCalculate & Caption: Calculate
5. Double Click on the CommadButton and import the below code:

**Code:**

```
Private Sub cdbCalculate_Click()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim cnrtl As Control
    Dim strMessageBox As String

    'Clear the string
    strMessageBox = ""

    'Set the rng you want
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    'Check if all values in the range are numeric to avoid errors
    For Each cell In rng

        If Not IsNumeric(cell) Then
            MsgBox "The value in column " & cell.Column & " , row " & cell.Row & " is not a number!", vbCritical
            'Stop the code
            End
        End If

    Next cell

    'Loop all Controls
    With Me

        For Each cnrtl In .Controls

            'Check if the control is checkbox
            If TypeName(cnrtl) = "CheckBox" Then

                'Check if the checkbox is checked and find the Max
                If cnrtl.Name = "cbxMax" And cbxMax.Value = True Then
                    strMessageBox = "Max value=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
                End If

                'Check if the checkbox is checked and find the Min
                If cnrtl.Name = "cbxMin" And cbxMin.Value = True Then
                    If strMessageBox = "" Then
                        strMessageBox = "Min value= " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
                    Else
                        strMessageBox = strMessageBox & vbNewLine & "Min value= " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
                    End If
                End If

                'Check if the checkbox is checked and find the Avarage
                If cnrtl.Name = "cbxAverage" And cbxAverage.Value = True Then
                    If strMessageBox = "" Then
                        strMessageBox = "Average value=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
                    Else
                        strMessageBox = strMessageBox & vbNewLine & "Avarage value= " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
                    End If
                End If

            End If

        Next cnrtl

        MsgBox strMessageBox, , "Results:"

    End With

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

**UserForm View:**

[image]